# What do grey rectangles means in repository description?

Tags: github

[image: screenshot][screenshot]:

Where I can read more about it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the commit activity for the repository. The higher the bar, the more commits made.

Unfortunately I can't find any reference to this! The closest I can find is information about other visualisations github offer: https://github.com/blog/1093-introducing-the-new-github-graphs